# how to customize app title in collapsed (for example: center or right align)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I can customize my `Actionbar`. But I can't customize it when the app is collapsed.

How to customize the app title when the app is collapsed (for example: center or right align)?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "When the app is collapsed"?

Comment: I Can't find how to costumize ActionBar in collapsed state

Comment: I changed the image to better understand what I mean

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that when you're in multitask mode, the appbar shows differently?

Comment: yes,Exactly. You understand true

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: OK , 
Thank you for your attention .Helped me .

Answer (score 0):

The color of the app bar in multitasking mode I believe is defined by the `android:colorPrimary` (or `colorPrimary` if you're using AppCompat) attribute in your styles.

I don't think you can change the alignment of the text of the app bar though.